# Skip specific value in sequence, using LINQ, IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array that contains the following values:

```
"admin", "superadmin", "user"
```

I try to skip the value which equals "user" only:

```
Roles.GetAllRoles().SkipWhile(v=>v.Equals("user"))
```

but the result still contains all 3 values. However if I put "admin" in Equals() the result will be:

```
"superadmin", "user"
```

How can I skip only "user"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527047/linq-is-skipwhile-broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LINQ Skip methods will only skip elements until they find one which doesn't match the condition.  Are you looking to filter the list?

```
Roles.GetAllRoles().Where(v=> !v.Equals("user"))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just using the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Something like

```
Roles.GetAllRoles().Where(v => !v.Equals("user"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `SkipWhile` was canceled right at the first element `admin`. Use `Where` instead like this:

```
Roles.GetAllRoles().Where(x=>x!="user");
```

If you still want to use `SkipWhile`, you have to order the list so that all the elements of `user` are placed continuously at the beginning:

```
Roles.GetAllRoles().OrderBy(x => x != "user").SkipWhile(x=>x.Equals("user"))
```