# C# Linq To Entities (SkipWhile not working)

Tags: c#, linq

I am calculating inventory based on stock transactions but I want to exclude those stock transactions whose invoice is not marked as **IsStocked** which is Nullable Boolean, I am trying to achieve this by using **SkipWhile** which is not working and it simply count all of transactions no matter it's invoice **IsStocked** property is true or false:

Here is what I tried:

```
public double GetInStockQuantity(Warehouse warehouse, Entities db)
{
    double res;
    try
    {
        res = db.Stocks.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.Product.ID == ID && c.WarehouseID == warehouse.ID).
            AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().
            SkipWhile(c => c.InvoiceItems.Any(q => q.Invoice.IsStocked == false)).Sum(q => q.Quantity);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        res = 0;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527047/linq-is-skipwhile-broken , your expectations of SkipWhile may be different

Answer (score 1):

You can try  **Where** clause.

```
    public double GetInStockQuantity(Warehouse warehouse, Entities db)
    {
        double res;
        try
        {
            res = db.Stocks.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.Product.ID == ID &&       c.WarehouseID == warehouse.ID).
            AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().
            Where(c => c.InvoiceItems.Any(q => q.Invoice.IsStocked == true)).Sum(q => q.Quantity);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           res = 0;
        }
          return res;
   }
```